# OpenCV4 - Deep Neural Network - dnn.hpp no such file or directory

Tags: qt, opencv, deep-learning

on my Debian laptop I've downloaded and compiled OpenCV4, with contrib extra modules, and everything seems to work fine; I can load an image in a Mat object and I can apply filter to it.

Now I want to try YOLO object detection so I tried to include the Deep Neural Network dnn module in my Qt project with

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

but when I compile the code I get this error

```
error: opencv2/dnn.hpp: No such file or directory
```

I've looked for OpenCV files, and here where I've found the dnn module

- usr/include/opencv
- usr/include/opencv2
- usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/dnn

Then I've tried to include

```
#include <opencv4/opencv2/dnn.hpp>
```

but I get the same error.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you add the main directory address of opencv to your project?

Comment: After CMake did you check then opencv_dnn module was enabled? It was compiled?

Comment: Check https://answers.opencv.org/question/117557/trying-to-run-dnn-module/. Apart from selecting dnn module you have to set path to opencv_contrib sources too.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstal the currently-install opencv with:

```
sudo apt remove libopencv-dev
```

Follow this tutorial to build openCV4 on your machine:

[How to Install OpenCV on Ubuntu 18.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Now do:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Now try to compile your code. The error should be gone.